# Necessary condition for periodic orbits in a non linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am studying this non linear ODE:

$$x''=x-x^3+\nu x x'$$

I have already shown that the origin is a saddle point and that (1,0), (-1,0) are non-linear centers (they are centers of the linearization and the system is reversible).

Now I am asked to show that a necessary condition for a periodic solution of this equation is

$$\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T x^4 dt > \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T x^2 dt$$

Where $T$ is the period of the solution. I get that the idea to prove this must be that any periodic solution spends much more time in the region where $\vert x \vert > 1$ than in the region where $\vert x \vert < 1$ but I haven't been able to give a rigorous proof.

How can I prove this rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** writing the equation in the form
$$
x'=y,\quad y'=x-x^3+\nu x y,
$$
we have
$$
\left(-x^2+\frac12x^4+y^2\right)'=-2(x-x^3)x'+2yy'=2\nu xy^2.
$$
So the best seems to be drawing the phase portrait for $\nu=0$ (without making linearizations!) and then deciding according to the sign of $2\nu xy^2$ where a periodic orbit can appear. The rest follows.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the argument and I almost got the result, but I don't know how to get rid of the 1/2 factor before the $x^4$ term. Could you detail that part a bit?

Comment: I thought about that before replying, but there is the word "necessary", not "equivalent". If nothing else it should come there. Otherwise a 1/2 could be missing.